# Recursively find child items and list in jinja

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to display "notes" in a nested list. Each note has a property called `parentID` that indicates a note that it is nested under.

Currently I am achieving a single level nest by doing this:

**models.py**

```
class Note(Model):
    title = CharField()
    tags = CharField()
    content = TextField()
    parentID = IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

**app.py**

```
def getSubnotes(note):
    note_id = note.id
    subnotes = models.Note.select().where(models.Note.parentID == note_id)
    return subnotes

app.jinja_env.globals.update(getSubnotes=getSubnotes)
```

**Index.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 medium-centered">
  <ul>
    {% for note in notes %}
      {% if note.parentID == 0 %}
      <li><a href="/n/{{note.getHash()}}">{{ note.title }}</a></li>
      <ul>
        {% for subnote in getSubnotes(note) %}
        <li><a href="/n/{{subnote.getHash()}}">{{ subnote.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to, however, recursively find all children notes of a single note and list them out, so there are nests of nests.

I have seen this as an example of how to recursively list in jinja (from [jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for)):

```
<ul class="sitemap">
{%- for item in sitemap recursive %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.href|e }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {%- if item.children -%}
        <ul class="submenu">{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
    {%- endif %}</li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

However I am confused about what `.children` actually is. How is it referencing itself or `items` of the same type?

How would I go about doing this recursively or is there a better method for achieving the same thing?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the example from the docs, I think that `item.children` is just an iterable of items of the same type. Then `{{ loop(item.children) }}` causes the current loop to be executed over the iterable `item.children` creating a nested list.

You can verify this:

```
import jinja2

templ = """
{%- for item in items recursive %}
    {{item.name}}
    {%- if item.children %}
        {{- loop(item.children) }}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
"""

items = [{'name': 'Bobby'},
         {'name': 'Jack',
          'children': [
              {'name': 'Jake'},
              {'name': 'Jill'}]},
         {'name': 'Babby', 'children': []}]

template = jinja2.Template(templ)
print(template.render(items=items))
```

prints out

```
Bobby
Jack
Jake
Jill
Babby
```

So in your example, I think you should be able to do something like

```
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 medium-centered">
  <ul>
    {% for note in notes recursive %}
      {% if note.parentID == 0 %}
      <li><a href="/n/{{note.getHash()}}">{{ note.title }}</a></li>
      <ul>
        {{ loop(getSubnotes(note)) }}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

as long as `getSubnotes(note)` returns empty if the note has no subNotes.

Answer (score 1):

Even more complete, in my opinion (it explores lists and dictionaries inside lists):

```html
<dl class="row">
  {% for key, value in json.items() recursive %}
  {% set outer_loop = loop %}
  <dt class="col-3">{{ key }}</dt>
  <dd class="col-9">
  {% if value is string %}
    {{ value }}
  {% elif value is mapping %}
    <dl class="row">
      {{ loop(value.items()) }}
    </dl>
  {% elif value is iterable %}
    <ol>
    {% for item in value %}
      <li>
      {% if item is mapping %}
        <dl class="row">
          {{ outer_loop(item.items()) }}
        </dl>
      {% else %}
        {{ item }}
      {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
  {% else %}
    {{ value }}
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
```

I wonder if/how could be simplified.